# The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda expression error

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

I have  this function:

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<RegionBreif>> GetAsync()
    {

    return await Table.Where(x => x.SiteId == _siteId).Select(r => new RegionBreif
    {
        IsServiceable = await RegionBreif.checkIfServicable(Context, r.SiteId, r.Id)
    }).ToArrayAsync();
}
```

And this function:

```
public static async Task<bool?> checkIfServicable(DbContext context, int? _siteId, int _regionId)
{
    var t = (from ir in context.Set<InspectionReview>()
             join so in context.Set<SiteObject>() on ir.ObjectId equals so.Id
             where so.SiteRegionId == _regionId && so.SiteId == _siteId
             select (bool?)
             ir.IsNormal);

    return t.Count() == 0 ? (bool?)null : t.Any(x => x.Value == false) ? false : true;
}
```

On this row:

```
await RegionBreif.checkIfServicable(Context, r.SiteId, r.Id)
```

I get this error:

Error   13  The 'await' operator can only be used within an async lambda expression. Consider marking this lambda expression with the 'async' modifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is in the lambda expression you pass to the `Select`. If you want to make use of the `await` inside the type create, `RegionBreif`, you have to pass an `async` lambda expression as below:

```
Select(async r => new RegionBreif
{
    IsServiceable = await RegionBreif.checkIfServicable(Context, r.SiteId, r.Id)
})
```

Comment: Note, this will now make `ToArrayAsync()` rerun a `Task<Task<T>[]>` instead of a `Task<T[]>`.